# Chainloading to WDS from iPXE with UEFI

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, uefi, ipxe

I am in the process of configuring our WDS server to support booting multiple OSes over the network. We have this set up and working using PXELinux for BIOS systems, but need to support UEFI systems going forward.

I have iPXE loading and displaying a menu correctly, but when attempting to chainload to WDS using the command below it just gets stuck in a loop of constantly reloading the menu after contacting the WDS Server.

`set next-server 0.0.0.0` (Replaced with IP of WDS Server)

`chain tftp://${next-server}/boot\\x64uefi\\wdsmgfw.efi`

If I do the preceeding and set it to run

`chain tftp://${next-server}/boot\\x64uefi\\bootmgfw.efi`

It loads the file and then stops on a blue screen, eventually shutting down.

I am basically looking to get a menu looking like so, but cannot figure out how to get to WDS.

- Windows Deployment Services
- Install Ubuntu 18.04
- Install Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to get the chainloading from iPXE → WDS working with the following commands.

```
set next-server 0.0.0.0  # Replace with WDS server IP address
set filename /boot/x64/bootmgfw.efi
set net0.dhcp/filename:string /boot/x64/bootmgfw.efi
set proxydhcp/filename:string /boot/x64/bootmgfw.efi
chain /boot/x64/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: Depending on usecase, iPXEs wimboot might be a better solution in terms of speed, stability and configurability. But not always.